# How to pass a function only after an entire array has been read and not for each element?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I'm trying to run a function when reading an array, but instead of running the function to each element, which I'm currently using `forEach` for, I want to make the script to read the entire array and then pass a function.

What I'm trying to say is this:

```
data.forEach(movie => {
    // Log each movie's title
    //console.log(movie.title);

    // Check if the userWord matches
    if (movie.title.toUpperCase().includes(userWord.toUpperCase())) {
        alert("YES");                   
    } else {
        alert("NO").
    }
});
```

Let's say my array is: `array = ["Aa", "Ba", "Ca", "Da"];`

If the user enters: **a**, then the script would `alert("YES")` four times, and I want to make it alert just once, at the end of the iteration.

For the same example, if the users enters: **B**, then the script would first `alert("NO")` once, then `alert("YES")`, then `alert("YES")` 2 times, and I want to make it just `alert("YES")`once, in the end.

Finally, if the users enters: **Ferrari**, then the script would `alert("NO")` four times, and I just want it to `alert("NO")` at the end.

I tried to make it very clear here, that's why the three "cases" of what is happening.

In the end, I want to know if there is a method that is kinda the opposite of the `forEach` or the common `for`. Something that just executes the function after reading the entire array.

Comment: Do you want to check if there is a movie that matches or not?

Comment: Exactly @ibrahimmahrir and I already can do it, but i'm having problem in printing an answer for the user.

Comment: Do you really need to loop the entire array? Can't you just stop at the first matched element if it exist?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir actually I want to show if there are matches AND what matches were found. But I think that with the `some()` structure that people answered down below, I can achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change the alert to a bool variable
2. Remove else (it would only overwrite any match)
3. if bool statement outside the loop to perform actions

if you want a list of the results, you should store the names in an array and outside of the loop - print.

see below:

Non-loop method:

```
data = ["test","hello", "hello1"];
search = "lo"; 
const matches = data.filter(movie => movie.includes(search));

alert(matches) //array of only matches - only has hello and hello 1
```

I don't know if there are performance gains against a loop... I suppose you could do a side by side comparison on a large dataset

Loop method:

```
var matches = "";
data.forEach(movie => {
    // Check if the userWord matches
    if (movie.title.toUpperCase().includes(userWord.toUpperCase())) {
        matches += movie.title + "<br> ";
    }
});

if (matches.length > 0)
{
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = matches;
} else {
    alert("No match found");
}
```

You'll see more customization on the first loop, but I think filtering data first is the way to go.

Comment: What language is this code written? Javascript is not a typed language. Did you mean `var matches = "";`?

Comment: I think that this is exactly what I'm looking for. I did not think about storing it in another array, but now you and other people gave this hint. Amazing, thanks!

Comment: And with that, I can now post comments :)

There might be a non-loop way of doing it as loops can be slow for large data-sets...

Comment: Got it, by large-data sets; how much is large? I mean, if I had to loop through an array of 100k elements? I'm really new in JS so many things are not clear.

Comment: I've added a non-loop method too, this returns an array of only results so you would still need a loop to customize, just the data is filtered.

@samuellawrentz had it further down. not sure what is better performance wise though.

Comment: quick googles and Map/Reduce/Filter/Find are slow because of a few reasons, some of them are:


1. They have a call back to execute so that act as an overhead.

2. Javascript function considers getters, sparse array and checking if arguments are passed as an array or not which adds up to overhead.


ref: https://hackernoon.com/javascript-performance-test-for-vs-for-each-vs-map-reduce-filter-find-32c1113f19d7

Answer (score 1):

I think closest what you can get is [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). Here is example

```js
let data = ["test","hello", "hello1"];
let userWord = "el";
let res =  data.some(movie => movie.toUpperCase().includes(userWord.toUpperCase()));
console.log(res) // prints true- means there was at least one "match", so you can alert
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `filter` array function to filter array elements that match your criteria and then finally alert only if a match is found. Using this method you could get all the elements that have matched to your `userWord`. That is, the `match` array will contain all the possible matches.

```js
var data = ['Aa', 'Bb', 'Cc', 'Dd'];
var flag = false;
var userWord = 'F'
var match = data.filter(movie => movie.indexOf(userWord) !== -1);
if(match.length)
console.log('YES');
else
console.log('NO');
```

Comment: Storing it in another array is the catch here for me, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, I believe you want to execute something if a predicate matches at least one of the items in the array (correct me if I'm wrong). For that you can use the `some` method like so:

```
if (movies.some((movie) => movie.toUpperCase().includes(userWord.toUpperCase()))) {
  alert('YES');
} else {
  alert('NO');
}
```